# How to update map in azure integration account

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Can you update an existing map in the Azure portal?
So far I can't figure out a way to edit or update an existing map.
I'm using an XSLT map with logic apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on it first and then re-upload it ...

[image]

You can also download the existing if you've misplaced it locally.

[image]